# How to pass Parent props to Children, when rendering using this.props.children() and React.cloneElement?

Tags: reactjs

```
<CheckboxGroup name="fruits" value={fruits} onChange={this.setFruits}>
    {(cb) => (
      <>
        <label>
          <Checkbox value="apple" /> Apple
        </label>
        <label>
          <Checkbox value="orange" /> Orange
        </label>
        <label>
          <Checkbox value="watermelon" /> Watermelon
        </label>
      </>
    )}
  </CheckboxGroup>
```

Here is the parent component. I want to pass the name, value and onChange to the children.

```
class CheckboxGroup extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: this.props.value,
      name: this.props.name
    }
  }
  render() {
    const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children(), child => {
      return React.cloneElement(child);
    });
   return(
     <>
      {children}
     </>
   )
  }
  }
  class Checkbox extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
   super(props);
 }
 render() {
   console.log(this.props);
   return (
     <>
       <input type="checkbox" value="" name=""  />
     </>
   );
 }
}
```

How to get the props from parents in children? I am using `this.props.children()` not `this.props.children`. From parent, I have tried React.cloneElement(child, {this.props}) but does not work.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use React.cloneElement? Your example doesn't appear to need anything special this API provides.

Comment: Hey @LyndenNoye I wanted to use cloneElement, so that I can use ''' <label>
          <Checkbox value="apple" /> Apple
        </label>''' as it is. just need the name and values in the child component. Is there any other way around?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a need to use the cloneElement API. You should be able to accomplish what you're after with something much simpler.

We can provide our data (i.e. the fruits) at the very top level, and use the data structure to map over each item to render a checkbox component with the name, value and onChange callback. No need to clone anything, and our components have no state of their own, so they can be simple function components.

```js
const Checkbox = ({ name, value, onChange, isChecked }) => (
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name={name}
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    checked={isChecked}
  />
)

const CheckboxGroup = ({ name, values, onChange, selectedValues }) => (
  <div>
    {values.map((value, index) => (
      <label key={index}>
        <Checkbox
          {...{ name, value, onChange }}
          isChecked={selectedValues.includes(value)}
        />
        {value}
      </label>
    ))}
  </div>
)

// an example implementation...

const theFruits = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange']

const MyFruitForm = () => {
  const [selectedFruits, setSelectedFruits] = React.useState([])
  const handleChange = (event) =>
    setSelectedFruits((oldFruits) => {
      if (event.target.checked) {
        return [...oldFruits, event.target.value]
      } else {
        return oldFruits.filter((fruit) => fruit !== event.target.value)
      }
    })
  return (
    <CheckboxGroup
      name="fruit-checkboxes"
      values={theFruits}
      onChange={handleChange}
      selectedValues={selectedFruits}
    />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyFruitForm />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I want to render the checkboxes as a child component of the parent CheckboxGroup. Hence I need to use the cloneElement. Thank you so much, Lynden for your effort. Really appreciate it.

Comment: You don't need to use cloneElement to accomplish a common task in React like rendering the checkboxes as a child component. I wonder why you are looking to obfuscate where your input elements will get their onChange handler from by using cloneElement like this?

Comment: @LyndenNoye you may use React.cloneElement for the benefit of the flexibility of the compound component pattern. https://kentcdodds.com/blog/compound-components-with-react-hooks